# Windows word *.doc icon

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, icons, microsoft-office-2007

I recently installed office after clean install. then my genius brother decided to make notepad the default open with with *.doc files. when I reassigned it to open with Word 2007, i got that horrible icon above. while the *.docx looks like it normally would. I would like to reset it to look like it normally would.

Please help. My brother's life depends on it.

edit: I cant upload pictures not enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs >Set Associations.

Didn't resolve the issue? Follow the steps below.

#### Run the Detect and Repair feature ([*Source*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924611))

- Click Start.
- If you are running Windows Vista or Windows 7, copy and paste (or type) the following command in the Search programs and files box, and then press ENTER: `appwiz.cpl`
- Click the name of the Microsoft Office Edition 2007 that you want to change, and then click Change.
- Click the option Repair, and then click  Continue.

Comment: the problem i am having has to do with the icon used to represent it. not getting it to open with word.

Comment: Please post a screenshot.

Comment: Try the new step and update me please.

Comment: did not work. I will posting a screenshot soon.